# Junit, Mockito, how to test a callbacks

Tags: java, junit, mockito, easymock

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Intercept object on method invocation with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244341/intercept-object-on-method-invocation-with-mockito)

I have an class that can mapp from one format to another. Since this is legacy code I don't dare to rewrite it, it is basically a set of plugins so if I change one I might have to change all the other. It wasn't developed with testing in mind.
So this is my problem.

```
interface Mapper {
    void handle(ClassA classA);
    void handle(ClassB classB);
}

public interface Publisher {
    public void publish(MappedClass mappedClass);
}

class MyMapper implements Mapper {

    private Publisher publisher;
    public void setPublisher(final Publisher publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public handle(ClassA classA) {
        final MappedClass mappedClass = // Map from ClassA to MappedClass
        publisher.publish(mappedClass);
    }

    public handle(ClassB classB) {
        final MappedClass mappedClass = // Map from ClassB to MappedClass
        publisher.publish(mappedClass);
    }
}
```

Okay. So depending on which class was "handled" `MappedClass` will be published with different values, and it is the values I want to verify (test). The problem is that I will get a test where I first have to write code that tests that the `publish` method is called,

```
private boolean wasCalled;

@Test
public void testClassAMapped() {
    wasCalled = false;
    final MyMapper myMapper = new MyMapper();
    myMapper.setPublisher(new Publisher() {
        public void publish(final MappedClass mappedClass) {
            wasCalled = true;
           // Code for verifying the fields in mappedClass
        });
    }
    final ClassA classA = // Create classA
    myMapper.handle(classA);
    assertTrue(wasCalled);
}
```

So first we create our mock `Publisher` which will first set the state of `wasCalled` to `true` so we know this method was ever called (this example is simplified so there is actually a dispatcher in the code... legacy code so I don't want to change it), second I want to verify that `MappedClass` has the correct field values.
What I would like to know is if anyone knows a better way to test this? The `wasCalled`, and `wasCalled` check becomes more or less boilerplate code for many of my tests, but since I don't want to add that much clutter (own hacks, test base classes, etc) I would like to know if there is a way to do this in Mockito, or EasyMock?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use an [Mockito ArgumentCaptor](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html)

```
@Test
public void test(){
  Publisher publisher = Mockito.mock(Publisher.class);
  myMapper.setPublisher(publisher);
  ArgumentCaptor<MappedClass> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MappedClass.class);

  ....
  myMapper.handle(...);
  ...

  verify(publisher).publish(captor.capture());
  MappedClass passedValue = captor.getValue();
  // assert stuff here
}
```

Comment: Cool. This might actually be what I am looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure I fully understand the problem, but it looks like you are looking for `Mockito.verify(publisher).publish(Matchers.isA(MappedClass.class));`

For that to work, you'd have to mock the `Publisher` through
`Publisher publisher = Mockito.mock(Publisher.class)`
and then hand that into `MyMapper`.

If you need to assert the state of the `MappedClass`, use an `ArgumentCaptor`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244341/intercept-object-on-method-invocation-with-mockito/12244564#12244564) for an example.

The [Mockito-API-doc](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html) has many additional examples.

Comment: The problem is just that I want to get rid of the wasCalled but still be able to verify that the fields in MappedClass is correct, and if I mock Publisher.class I won't be able to verify the fields in MappedClass.
I don't even know if there is a solution to my problem, just wanted to ask the question to see if anyone with experience with Mockito or EasyMock have seen this problem before.

Comment: Is it important that the fields are filled correctly?  Couldn't you just check that the behaviour conforms to your expectations?

Comment: I have amended the answer to get you started with assertions on the ``MappedClass``.

Comment: Yes, since there is logic in MyWrapper which decides which value a field should get depending on if it is ClassA or ClassB that gets "published". I don't know where else to test this.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. ArgumentCaptor was the solution. However I marked the answer below as correct as it was spot on.